# How can a java program find itself has experienced a long GC pause?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, monitor

I am writing a program that can have long GC pauses, however the SLA said I shouldn't have too many of them. And it needs to report if it finds any.

How can I make it monitor itself? I don't want to parse GC logs.

JMX exposes LastGcInfo, but I don't know when to query it.

Comment: Have you considered using any APM-like application? Forcing an application to monitor itself and report on errors/events might not be a good choice on a scaling infrastructure.

Comment: How many are "too many of them"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good idea to let application handle GC relate monitoring in user code space. Sometime application is in the state (close to OOM), where it won't be able to execute user code and monitoring can remain broken.

If you want to do this anyways (at your risk), you can hook the listeners to GC like this and inspect GC duration.

```
for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gcBean : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
    NotificationEmitter emitter = (NotificationEmitter) gcBean;
    emitter.addNotificationListener(new CustomNotificationListener(), null, null);
}
```

and

```
class CustomNotificationListener implements javax.management.NotificationListener {
        @Override
        public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
            // hook your logic here.
          String notifType = notification.getType();
          if (notifType.equals(GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION)) {
              // retrieve the garbage collection notification information
              CompositeData cd = (CompositeData) notification.getUserData();
              GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo info = GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.from(cd);
              System.out.println(info.getGcInfo().getDuration());
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jigar's answer shows how you could monitor the GC events.  However, I don't think this would allow a thread to measure how long it ... or another thread ... was paused.

And in fact, I suspect that there isn't a way to measure that.

Indeed, I don't think there is a way to measure other kinds of pauses either; e.g.

- pauses due to waiting on I/O
- pauses due to synchronization, or
- pauses due to OS controlled time slicing.

I don't think what you want to do is feasible, let alone advisable.

---

Looking at your requirements:

> I am writing a program that can have long GC pauses, however the SLA said I shouldn't have too many of them. And it needs to report if it finds any.

1. The SLA is probably not couched in terms of GC pauses<sup>1</sup>.  It will be couched in terms of response times.  That makes a lot of difference. Response times are a lot easier to measure than GC pauses.
2. It is unlikely that the SLA says you have to measure the response times (or whatever) in the application itself.  So measure it on the outside:

   - Analyze application / web container log events in a separate real time monitoring system; e.g. Nagios, CheckMk, etcetera.
   - Scan the application / web container log files after the fact.
   - Hook up packet or flow monitoring to something that records response times.

If you decide to ignore 2), consider that any extra infrastructure you put into your Java application to "self monitor" is going to make it more complex, and (unless you are careful) add to the GC load, making GC pauses *more frequent*.

In short: since you are probably not required to do this, my considered advice is to NOT try to detect GC pauses in the application itself.

---

<sup>1 - If it is, then someone made a mistake in writing / negotiating the SLA!</sup>

Comment: Well, the SLA didn't mention GC I believe. But my leader said I am responsible for GC pauses.

Comment: Good.  So that means that you are not obligated your monitoring in a way that won't work.  My advice to use one of the alternative ways to measure / monitor **response** time.

Answer (score 0):

Before jumping straight to a paid Java APM application or ad-hoc implementations, take a look at [Glowroot](https://glowroot.org/).

It is free and opensource, providing you the possibility to monitor a bunch of metrics, including GC collection time, Heap usage. It is also possible to send e-mails with alerts to you and your collaborators.

Little [overhead](https://glowroot.org/overhead.html) will be noticed. I've been using it for a while for applications with little or no budget at all.

Give it a try(here is a [demo](https://demo.glowroot.org/)), then pick an APM that suits your needs better.